# heatmap2 graph doesn't display complete dataset

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm using `gplots::heatmap.2`to make heatmap of my matrix. The variables in columns and rows are actually the same. But the graph doesn't show complete data in y-axis.

```
structure(c(NA, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, NA, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, NA), .Dim = c(10L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")))
```

[image]

This omission seems has nothing to do with the dataset or the margin of the graph. I also tried another different dataset with different variables in row and column, but still there is omission in y-axis.
Thank you!

Comment: Just stretch the figure in the vertical dimension. R will only show axis tick labels if they are readable. You can also try to make them smaller.

Comment: OHHH Silly me!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options.

1. Manually stretch the figure vertically after the plot appears.
2. Send the figure to a file, specifying the height and width

   `tiff(filename = "Heatmap.tif", width = 480, height = 480) # Modify as required
   heatmap.2(data_object) # Or whatever you called your data frame
   dev.off()`
3. Modify the size of the tick labels in the call to `heatmap.2`

   `heatmap.2(df, cexRow = 0.7)`